# How to connect Wii U to monitor and speakers

Tags: wii-u, audio-hardware

I have a Wii U that I would like to play on my monitor. I have a number of other devices connected to the monitor, so I use a [five-way HDMI switch](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008D6YZXG) to control the visual input. When I connect my PC or Wii (using [Wii 2 HDMI](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00GRQAMJA)), I have no issues. For my PC, I connect my video using the HDMI switch and the audio to another audio switch that goes to my speakers. With the Wii, the Wii 2 HDMI separates HDMI video from audio, which then go to their respective devices and work normally.

However, I have had some issues with the Wii U. I first tried going from the HDMI port to the switch, but then only the video would show up and there would be no audio. I then tried to use an HDMI switch and a Wii Component cable, as recommended [here](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1545/~/how-to-use-the-wii-u-console-with-an-external-speaker-system). I located the settings on the Wii U to put video over the HDMI cable and audio through the Wii Component Cable, but the audio still did not work. Finally, I tried my same setup with the Wii by purchasing another Wii 2 HDMI adapter (because it separates audio and visual signals). I used the HDMI from the Wii 2 HDMI to go to my HDMI switch and the audio to my speakers, *just like I did with my Wii*. However, the Wii U will not output a visual signal (the monitor does not recogize any inputs) when the resolution is set to anything other than 480p or 480i, and the audio *still* doesn't work!

Is there any way I can connect my Wii U to a separate set of speakers? Can I use something that strips the audio away from HDMI and puts it into a 3.5mm jack, perhaps [something like this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01DKC5FEK)?

Comment: HDMI has audio channels in it. Get a switch that supports them properly. Split the audio on the output side, if you must, not the input side.

Answer (score 1):

Switch that separate audio and video from HDMI exists. Like that you can first put your 5 way switch, then the one splitting audio and video, and you will no longer need a switch for sound as the sound coming out will be from the HDMI chosen with your first switch.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are suggesting?

Comment: I'm using this one https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B00T2S7P90/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: Just to let you know the one I linked you was the cheapest I found in France, but I would advise you to test another one if there are more where you live, as the on I linked has a bad point : when your screen is switched off, the switch device is still on and send a blue background to your screen. So you'll have to turn off the screen each time to not have a blue light freezed on your screen. (sorry for bad english as it's a little hard to explain and I'm french)